# Loop Preg_match until no more matches

Tags: php, regex, loops, curl, preg-match

How can I preg_match until no more results is found?

I'm using curl to login a page and then delete posts from there.

But to delete those posts I need to preg_match the content and filter the IDs and if found ids there my script run the delete command.

So, basically:

```
$pattern = '/(?<=list_id=).*?(?=&cmd=edit)/s';
preg_match($pattern, $LoginResult, $id); //THIS PREG_MATCH IS WORKING, IT GETS THE FIRST RESULT OF THE PAGE (WHAT I NEED). BUT I NEED TO MAKE A LOOP TO THIS SCRIPT RUN OVER AND OVER UNTIL NOTHING MORE IS FOUND.
$idpagina = $id[0];
```

In words it should make something like:

- If > preg_match is true > run delete command.
- Loop If until preg_match is false.

With this code I can find everything there is between **list_id=** and **&cmd=edit**. If the script find something between this two strings, It needs to perform a curl to delete this ID:

```
//THIS IS WORKING
$paginadelete = "https://example/list/folder/0?list_id=".$idpagina."&cmd=delete&type=AD_DELETE";


    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $paginadelete);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $step1 = curl_exec($login);
    echo $step1;
```

What this basically does is (or should do):

1. Loop preg_match and if preg_match is true go to #2
2. Run Delete Curl
3. Return to #1 until nothing is found in preg_match

But this script run 3 curl processes:

1. Login
2. Go to delete page (this one above)
3. Confirm delete

So this loop should be between step #2 and #3 until nothing more is found.

My #3 step (confirm delete) is this one:

```
$url = curl_getinfo($login, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$url = substr($url, 9);
$url = "http://example.com/cmd/act/".$url;

$post_data = array(
'1' => 'delete',
'2' => '1',
'3' => '2',
'4' => '10',
'5' => '',
'6' => 'continue',
);

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}


//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);


curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
$step2 = curl_exec($login);
//echo $step2;
```

***////////////////////// EDIT***

I was trying:

```
if (preg_match('/(?<=list_id=).*?(?=&cmd=edit)/s', $LoginResult, $id)){
}
else {
}
```

But this will only work for the first result. After that, the script stops. I need to re-run the if until preg_match is false and then end in the else.

I thought about using DO and WHILE, but I don't know how and neither if it'll work.

**////////////////// EDIT 2**

I'm now trying to use a GOTO until get false and close connection

```
verification:
if (preg_match('/(?<=list_id=).*?(?=&cmd=edit)/s', $LoginResult, $id)){
[..........]
} else {
//close the connection
curl_close($login);      
}
goto verification;
```

But doesn't seem to work, lol.

Comment: why are you using regex to parse querystring parameters? why not use the built in php functions that perform the action for you like [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) or [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) or even just access the `$_GET` variable?

Comment: Have you tried using [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)?

Comment: @iam-decoder because this URL is in a input, and not the header.

Comment: @PedroPinheiro yes... but I thought would not be a good idea, because this post page will have lots of pages... I prefer the script check everytime if a ID exists in the page.

Comment: @Diego, I cannot understand your question: "How can I preg_match until no more results is found?". You either use preg_match_all to perform a global regexp and use the third parameter, or you put preg_match_all inside a loop to check several strings.

Comment: @Diego `parse_str()` will parse an input query string into a variable array.. Regardless if you're adamant about using Regex then you should make sure that Regex control characters are escaped if you need the textual representation matched, like `?`

Comment: If I use preg_match_all it will only make an array for the first page. And I will have to run this loop over many and many pages. Using a loop for preg_match I could always get the first result. So instead of removing all posts from a page at once (using preg_match_all) it would be better if the script always load the page and search for the first result. At some time deleting the first posts, there will be no one left to delete. Got it?

Comment: @iam-decoder take a look in the regex part, I have made a comment there.

Comment: Why don't you want all posts deleted simultaneously? What's the gain from extra loading and time spent on the action?

Comment: @iam-decoder there is no problem about deleting simultaneously... But if I do this, I will have to make a new script to run over pages... Because it will only work for the first page... Let's say each page have 30 results, and in total I have 90 posts to delete, If I delete simultaneously only the first 30 will be deleted because the script will not visit next page (or let's say, will visit the same page with new results).

Comment: @Diego do you not have access to the database or something?

Comment: @iam-decoder Nope... it's a third party website... I need to perform this via curl.

Comment: I think what this means is you should work on your script to aggregate all the information by pagination and then looping through `preg_match_all()` on the final result.

Comment: This would demand even more resources, don't you think? I would need to make the script to make only one array (or merge many arrays based on each page). Doing a "refresh" in the IF until it becomes false, seems more logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your first edit, It seems that what you are trying to achieve is the following:

```
while(preg_match('/(?<=list_id=).*?(?=&cmd=edit)/s', $LoginResult, $id)) {
    // do stuff
}
// do stuff after the preg_match is false
```

**Edit**:

Based on your description on the comments maybe this code will satisfy your needs.

```
while(true) {
    $result = preg_match('/(?<=list_id=).*?(?=&cmd=edit)/s', $LoginResult, $id);
    if($result) {
        // Run Delete Curl
    } else {
        curl_close($login);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll test this one... I'm just adding new posts in the control panel and I'll try to delete. Asap I give my feedback here :D Thanks.

Comment: Well... The script keeps running, it deletes only the first result. And yeah... the page keeps running...

Comment: In the ``//do stuff`` part you need to specify some condition to break the loop or change the ``$LoginResult`` maybe using [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. In the '// do stuff after the preg_match is false' I closed the curl connection 'curl_close($login);' even though it didn't work.... Any idea?

Comment: @Diego, I updated the answer, see if that helps you.

Comment: Same problem, as soon as I run the script, it deletes the FIRST result only and the page keeps loading.... Any idea?

Comment: @Diego, The only way to do a ``preg_match`` until no more matches is to somehow **change** the variable ``$LoginResult`` on each iteration until you end up with a string that the regex does not match. You haven't answered me if you are doing that.

Comment: no ideia how to to that.... I'm afraid to change the $LoginResult and brake at the beginning the script.

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't clear, but I guess what you need is `preg_match_all`, i.e.:

```
    preg_match_all('/((?<=list_id=).*?(?=&cmd=edit))/im', $html, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {

       //here you can implement an if/else to check if the ID exist
        echo $matches[1][$i];
    }
```

---

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: I think Pedro Pinheiro answer's is more what I need.
Preg_match_all will not work so well in this case.